# Looping through table rows with if conditions in tbody

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<div>
<table class="table table-striped" id="mytab">
  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th class="col col-1">Symbol</th>
      <th class="col col-2">Name</th>
      <th class="col col-3">Total Shares</th>
      <th class="col col-4">Purchase Price</th>
      <th class="col col-5">Current Price</th>
      <th class="col col-6">Percent Change</th>
      <th class="col col-7">Profit/Loss</th>
      <th class="col col-8">Total</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
  {% for stock in stocks %}
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ stock["symbol"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock["name"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock["sumshares"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock["purchase_p"] | usd }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock['ap'] | usd }}</td>
        <td id="Perc_change">{{ stock['perc_change'] }}</td>
        <td id="prolos">{{ stock['prolos'] | usd }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock['total'] | usd }}</td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
  <div align="right" style=padding-bottom:20px>
      <h4>Cash: {{ availableCash | usd }}</h4> 
  </div>
    <div align="right">
      <h4>Total Value: {{ grandTotal | usd }}</h4> 
  </div>
  
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
          var value=document.getElementById('Perc_change').innerHTML;
          if (value>0) {
            document.getElementById('Perc_change').style.color="green";
            document.getElementById('Perc_change').innerHTML += "%";
            document.getElementById('Perc_change').innerHTML += "&#x25B2";
            document.getElementById('prolos').style.color="green";
          } 
          if(value<0) {
            document.getElementById('Perc_change').style.color="red";
            document.getElementById('Perc_change').innerHTML += "%";
            document.getElementById('Perc_change').innerHTML += "&#x25BC";
            document.getElementById('prolos').style.color="red";
          }
    });
    
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

What I am trying to do is to write a for loop that will go over each row (could be many stocks in Index) and execute the JS written below. (note: I have removed the for loop I had as it did not work) the current script is working where there is only one row in the Index.

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, which you are violating with `id="Perc_change"` and `id="prolos"` inside the loop.

Comment: And both `thead` and `tbody` must have table _rows_ as children, not table _cells_ directly. And sticking each record into its _own_ `tbody`, usually doesn't make too much sense either.

Comment: How can I add a unique ID for each iteration of the loop? Regarding <tr> I have updated the code as above, this what you meant?

Comment: why do you even need javascript for this? Why is the template not just doing these things?

Comment: _"How can I add a unique ID for each iteration of the loop?"_ - append a loop counter, or increment your own counter variable inside the loop ... can't tell you anything more specific, because so far we don't even know what kind of templating language you are even using there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using Jinja so if anyone will be of interest this what I have done:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<div>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Total Shares</th>
      <th>Purchase Price</th>
      <th>Current Price</th>
      <th>Percent Change</th>
      <th>Profit/Loss</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  {% for stock in stocks %}
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ stock["symbol"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock["name"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock["sumshares"] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock["purchase_p"] | usd }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock['ap'] | usd }}</td>
        {% if stock['perc_change'] > 0 %}
          <td style="color:green;">&#x25B2;{{ stock['perc_change'] }}%</td>
          <td style="color:green;">{{ stock['prolos'] | usd }}</td>
        {% elif stock['perc_change'] < 0 %}
          <td style="color:red;">&#x25BC;{{ stock['perc_change'] }}%</td>
          <td style="color:red;">{{ stock['prolos'] | usd }}</td>
        {% else %}
          <td style="color:gray;">{{ stock['perc_change'] }}%</td>
          <td style="color:gray;">{{ 0.00 | usd }}</td>
        {% endif  %}
        <td>{{ stock['total'] | usd }}</td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
  <div style=padding-bottom:20px>
      <h4>Cash: {{ availableCash | usd }}</h4> 
  </div>
  <div style=padding-bottom:20px>
    <h4>Total Value: {{ grandTotal | usd }}</h4> 
  </div>
  <div>
    {% if totalprolos > 0 %}
      <h4 class="inline">Total Profit/Loss:</h4>
      <h4 class="inline" style="color:green;">&#x25B2;{{ totalprolos | usd }}</h4>
    {% elif totalprolos < 0 %}
      <h4 class="inline">Total Profit/Loss:</h4>
      <h4 class="inline" style="color:red;">&#x25BC;{{ totalprolos | usd }}</h4>
    {% else %}
      <h4 class="inline">Total Profit/Loss:</h4>
      <h4 class="inline" style="color:gray;">{{ totalprolos | usd }}</h4>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This will show on the table of stocks an arrow up and the percent change if the stock went up, and red if down. JS wasn't needed as Jinja has a more straightforward solution.